# Assigned access or guided access equivalent

Tags: users, restricted-access

Is there a way to restrict user to use only one app in ubuntu? In Windows it is assigned access feature and in iOS it is guided access feature.

Comment: You can set up something like a kiosk mode: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk and http://askubuntu.com/q/193906/158442.